# Python re.findall with * and **

Tags: python

using a re.findall, is it possible to list two subsequent occurences of * in the same index of the list?

lets say I have `str = "2**3 + 2*3"` I'd like the list to appear as

```
lis = re.findall('[\+\-*/()]', str)

lis = [2, **, 3, +, 2, *, 3]
```

is there some regex like `*|**` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+` after the char class which repeats the previous token one or more times.

```
lis = re.findall(r'[-+*/()]+|\d+', string)
```

or

```
lis = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z\d]+|[^\w\s]+', string)
```

Example:

```
>>> s = "2**3 + 2*3"
>>> re.findall(r'[-+*/()]+|\d+', s)
['2', '**', '3', '+', '2', '*', '3']
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Za-z\d]+|[^\w\s]+', s)
['2', '**', '3', '+', '2', '*', '3']
```

You may use `re.split` also,

```
>>> re.split(r'\s*([-+*/()]+)\s*', s)
['2', '**', '3', '+', '2', '*', '3']
```